# Implementing programmatic Spring AOP with ProxyFactory

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop, proxyfactory

I'm playing around with implementing Spring AOP programmatically.
I created a simple factory class that produces AOP Object.class proxies
with a given list of MethodInterceptors:

```
public class AOPProxyFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<Object> {

    private List<MethodInterceptor> methodInterceptors = new ArrayList<MethodInterceptor>();

    public Object getObject() throws Exception {
        Object o = new Object();
        ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory(o);
        for (MethodInterceptor methodInterceptor : methodInterceptors) {
            proxyFactory.addAdvice(methodInterceptor);
        }
        return proxyFactory.getProxy();
    }

    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return Object.class;
    }

    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return false;
    }

    public void setMethodInterceptors(List<MethodInterceptor> methodInterceptors) {
        this.methodInterceptors = methodInterceptors;
    }
```

A simple interceptor:

```
public class SimpleMethodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("SimpleMethodInterceptor: " + invocation.getMethod().getName());
        return invocation.proceed();
    }
}
```

Spring XML configuration:

```
<bean id="simpleMethodInterceptor" class="...SimpleMethodInterceptor"/>

<bean id="objectAOPProxyFactoryBean" class="...AOPProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="methodInterceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="simpleMethodInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In the docs [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/aop/framework/AdvisedSupport.html#addAdvice%28org.aopalliance.aop.Advice%29)
you can read the following about addAdvice(Advice advice): *'... Note that the given advice will apply to all invocations on the proxy, even to the toString() method!...'*

So, I'm expecting to get all calls to Object.class methods intercepted by SimpleMethodInterceptor.

Test:

```
@Test
public void aopTest() {
    Object o = (Object) applicationContext.getBean("objectAOPProxyFactoryBean");
    o.toString();
    o.equals(o);
    o.getClass();
}
```

gives this output:

*SimpleMethodInterceptor: toString*

It seems that only toString() method got intercepted. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odd. It seems like a bug to me. I can't explain why exactly, but I have a possible workaround. Create an interface and redefine equals and hashCode there:

```
public interface MadeUpInterface {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj);

    @Override
    public int hashCode();
}
```

Return that an instance that implements that interface from the proxy factory instead.

```
public Object getObject() throws Exception {
    Object o = new MadeUpInterface() {};
    ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory(o);
    for (MethodInterceptor methodInterceptor : methodInterceptors) {
        proxyFactory.addAdvice(methodInterceptor);
    }
    return proxyFactory.getProxy();
}
```

Now it will print equals and hashCode. So I think the behavior is that it doesn't intercept calls for methods that are defined only on Object. And toString is treated as a special case.

Comment: Should work without interface using CGLIB, check: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop-api.html#aop-pfb-proxy-types